# Publish:complete not fired when publishing through code

Tags: publishing, events

We have added an event to `publish:complete` and it is working fine when we publish in Sitecore (manually). However, when we do the exact same publish in code the event is not fired.

The code:

```
var publishOptions = new PublishOptions(item.Database, publishDb, PublishMode.Smart, lang, DateTime.Now);

var publisher = new Publisher(publishOptions);
publisher.Options.RootItem = item;
publisher.Options.Deep = true;
publisher.Publish();
```

The publish works but the event is not fired. Caches are cleared and it seems that the publish:end is fired, but not the complete (and we need that one).

Why is the complete not fired?

Sitecore version: 8.2-upd2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or not.. couldn't find a reference to it. But the issue got fixed by using a different approach (code) to do the publish:

```
PublishManager.PublishItem(item, new[] { publishDb }, new [] { lang }, true, true);
```

I checked the Sitecore code behind these and found that the Publisher does indeed trigger the publish:end but not the publish:complete.

If you search the numerous blog posts written about publishing programmatically you'll get both ways of publishing presented. But apparently they don't act the same. If you need the `publish:remote` events, remember to use the `PublishManager`.